# import in \newcommand in my package produces an error

Tags: macros, errors, packages, import

I have written and installed my own package `gym.sty`. In that package I defined

```
\newcommand{\loadgym}{\import{sagegym}}
```

since I need to execute some commands after `\begin{document}` for the package to be fully working. I tested it in a document that basically consists of

```
\usepackage{gym}
\begin{document}
\loadgym
\end{document}
```

The package all works fine and does all it is supposed to do including the `\loadgym` command. But it produces an error message which is annoying though harmless:

```
Paragraph ended before \@import was complete
```

Is there any way to avoid this error message? I do not know if it is relevant, but gym.sty and sagegym.tex are located in MiKTeX package folders whereas the document implementing the code is located elsewhere.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you show a bit of context about your usage of `\loadgym`? A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is needed.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't given an example or said which packages you are using, but I would guess you are using `\import` from the `import` package. According to the comments in the file the usage is

```
\import{/usr5/friend/work/}{report}
```

That is, it has two arguments and you have only used one.

Comment: It puzzled me too that it worked using only one argument. But the nice thing is that somehow my import-command finds sagegym.tex which is located in my package folder for the package gym.sty. How would I do that if I were to specify a path as first argument?

Comment: @Eskil sorry I don't have enough information to answer the question. Why do you need `\import` at all if the file is in your package folder it is presumably in tex's input path (if the package is found) so you could just use  the standard latex `\input{sagegym}`

Comment: I tried \input first. It said sagegym.tex not found.

Comment: @Eskil there is something you are not telling us (which is why we always ask for complete example code) If `\usepackage{gym}` finds `gym.sty` and `sagegym.tex` is in the same directory as `gym.sty` then `\input{sagegym}` will work. If it does not work, post a complete small document that shows the problem (including the smallest version of `gym.sty` that you can make that shows the problem) and post the full error message you get from TeX.

Comment: Right now I have no idea why it worked - I just tried to comment out irrelevant parts to submit a complete small version of my codes. But it did not work properly. I will ask a new question instead that tells what I am really trying to do. Thanks for your help!